# My footer won't center properly. It only centers when I remove the header <a> tags

Tags: html, css

As you can see, the footer at the bottom of the page is not centered properly. I noticed that the footer only centers when I remove the `<a>` tags under the `header`. Is there a reason why this is happening? How can I center my footer without removing the `<a>` tags under `header`?

```css
#myVideo{
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  z-index: 0; /* added so that the main header wont be affected by opacity*/
}

.container{
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Arian LifeStyle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PSI(copy).css" media="all">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/88ef366da2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <header>  
            <nav>
                <a href="#about" class="header">About</a>
                <a href="music" class="header">Music</a>
                <a href="videos" class="header">Videos</a>
                <a href="contact" class="header">Contact<a>
            </nav>
            <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo"><source src="Los Angeles.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        </header>
    </section>
    <section>
      <footer>
        <nav class="container">
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
      </footer>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the close tag here

```
<a href="contact" class="header">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html code was in an ugly state. There was no end tag `a` in the start tag of the `nav`.

```css
#myVideo{
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  z-index: 0; /* added so that the main header wont be affected by opacity*/
}

.container{
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Arian LifeStyle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PSI(copy).css" media="all">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/88ef366da2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <header>  
            <nav>
                <a href="#about" class="header">About</a>
                <a href="music" class="header">Music</a>
                <a href="videos" class="header">Videos</a>
                <a href="contact" class="header">Contact</a>
            </nav>
            <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo"><source src="Los Angeles.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        </header>
    </section>
    <section>
      <footer>
        <nav class="container">
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="footer-link" href="#link" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           
        </nav>
      </footer>
    </section>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a '/' or closing tag of the last 'a' tag inside nav, add that and hopefully it will fix it.

```
<a href="contact" class="header">Contact</a>
```